Please help put tags on [Untagged] questions!
We have burninated almost thirty useless, terrible, or ambiguous tags today, and could use some help:
Pick a question that has the untagged tag and fix the whole question:

title
grammar errors
typos
formatting
add tags that should be on the question.

Unless it is beyond saving: Then flag for closing/deletion.
Anyone can suggest edits! Feel free to join us in the Bitcoin Lounge if you have questions or just want to chat. :)

Some were even useless, terrible AND ambiguous. You just don't know the horrors, I ended up destroying the very fabric of morality in the process.
